# 500 Internal Server Error in crawler-script

Tags: php

I'm struggling with a my crawler-script giving me "500 Internal Server Error". I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the execution time of the script, but I don't know how to resolve that. I've been doing my research and I've found that often it has something to do with the .htaccess file, but I don't have one in my folders, and I've never made one myself.
So I guess it is just the server timing out somehow.
Here is my code:

```
  <?php
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
  set_time_limit(0);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$res5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM statuz ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($res5);

$status = $row5['status'];

if($status == '2' OR !isset($status)) {

$res10 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM crawler_queue WHERE status != 0");
$row10 = mysqli_num_rows($res10);

if($row10 == 0) {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO crawler_queue (crawler_id, status)
    (SELECT id,0 FROM crawlers)");
}

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO statuz (status) VALUES ('1')");

    $initial_res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT crawler_id,id FROM crawler_queue WHERE status = '0' LIMIT 1");
    while($initial_row = mysqli_fetch_array($initial_res)) {

        $config_id = $initial_row['id'];
        $start_crawler_id = $initial_row['crawler_id'];
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE crawler_queue SET status = '1' WHERE crawler_id = '$start_crawler_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

        $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT href_xpath,content_xpath,url,image_xpath,forfatter_xpath,dato_xpath,custom_url,custom_content,crawlers.newspaper_id AS newspaper_id, crawler_urls.id AS crawler_id, crawler_urls.rss AS rss, categories.id AS category_id, newspapers.name AS newspaper_name, crawlers.id AS id
        FROM crawlers
        INNER JOIN crawler_urls
        ON crawlers.newspaper_id = crawler_urls.newspaper_id
        INNER JOIN categories
        ON crawler_urls.category_id = categories.id
        INNER JOIN newspapers
        ON newspapers.id = crawlers.newspaper_id
        WHERE crawlers.id = '$start_crawler_id'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            $href = $row['href_xpath'];
            $url = $row['url'];
            $newspaper_id = $row['newspaper_id'];
            $crawler_id = $row['crawler_id'];
            $content_xpath = $row['content_xpath'];
            $image_xpath = $row['image_xpath'];
            $rss = $row['rss'];
            $dato_xpath = $row['dato_xpath'];
            $forfatter_xpath = $row['forfatter_xpath'];
            $category = $row['category_id'];
            $newspaper_name = $row['newspaper_name'];
            $custom_url = $row['custom_url'];
            $custom_content = $row['custom_content'];
            $id = $row['id'];

            $data = array();

            if($rss == '0') {

                            $html = new DOMDocument();
                            @$html->loadHtmlFile(''.$url.'');
                            $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
                            $nodelist_href = $xpath->query( "$href" );

                            foreach($nodelist_href as $node) 
                            {
                                if (substr($node->getAttribute("href"), 0, 1) === '/') {

                                    if(isset($custom_url)) {
                                        if($newspaper_id == 9) {
                                            $data['href'][] = "http://www.bloomberg.com". '' . $node->getAttribute("href");
                                        } else {
                                            $data['href'][] = $url. '' . $node->getAttribute("href") . '' . $custom_url;
                                        }

                                        $data['img_url'][] = $url. '' . $node->getAttribute("href");
                                        $data['title'][] = $node->nodeValue;
                                    } else {
                                        $data['href'][] = $url. '' . $node->getAttribute("href");
                                        $data['title'][] = $node->nodeValue;
                                    }

                                } else {

                                    if(isset($custom_url)) {
                                        $data['href'][] = $node->getAttribute("href"). '' . $custom_url;
                                        $data['img_url'][] = $node->getAttribute("href");
                                        $data['title'][] = $node->nodeValue;
                                    } else {
                                        $data['href'][] = $node->getAttribute("href");
                                        $data['title'][] = $node->nodeValue;
                                    }

                                }

                            }

            } else {

                        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

                        foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
                            if($newspaper_id == 3) {
                                $data['href'][] = $item->link . '' . $custom_url;
                                $data['img_url'][] = $item->link;
                            } else {
                                $data['href'][] = $item->link;
                            }
                            $data['title'][] = $item->title;
                        }

                    }

                        if(isset($data)) {

                                for($i=0;$i<count($data['href']);$i++) {

                                    $links_href = $data['href'][$i];
                                    $links_title = $data['title'][$i];
                                    $specific_img_url = $data['img_url'][$i];

                                    if($newspaper_id == '3') {
                                        $h = file_get_contents($links_href);
                                        eval($custom_content);

                                        $html = new DOMDocument();
                                        @$html->loadHtml($h);
                                    } else {
                                        $html = new DOMDocument();
                                        @$html->loadHtmlFile(''.$links_href.'');
                                    }

                                    $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
                                    $html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;          
                                    $nodelist_xpath = $xpath->query( "$content_xpath" );

                                    $data['content'][$i] = '';
                                    $content = $data['content'][$i];

                                        foreach($nodelist_xpath as $node)
                                        {
                                            $content .= $html->saveHTML($node);
                                        }

                                        if(isset($specific_img_url)) {
                                            $html = new DOMDocument();
                                            @$html->loadHtmlFile(''.$specific_img_url.'');
                                            $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
                                            $html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;          
                                            $img_href = $xpath->query( "$image_xpath" );

                                            foreach($img_href as $node) 
                                            {
                                                $is_img_there = $node->getAttribute("src");

                                                if (isset($is_img_there)) {
                                                    $data['img_src'][$i] = $node->getAttribute("src");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            $img_href = $xpath->query( "$image_xpath" );

                                            foreach($img_href as $node) 
                                            {
                                                $is_img_there = $node->getAttribute("src");

                                                if (isset($is_img_there)) {
                                                    $data['img_src'][$i] = $node->getAttribute("src");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }


                                            if(isset($data['img_src'][$i])) {

                                                if($newspaper_id == '33') {
                                                    $img_src = $data['img_src'][$i];
                                                    $img_src = str_replace("/sites/","",$img_src);
                                                } else {
                                                    $img_src = $data['img_src'][$i];
                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                $img_src = "";
                                            }

                                            $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i","",$content); 
                                            $content = preg_replace("/<script[^>]+\>/i","",$content);
                                            $content = preg_replace("/var startIndex.*/i","",$content);
                                            $content = str_replace("'","&apos;",$content);
                                            //$content = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $content);

                                            /*
                                            echo$newspaper_name;
                                            echo"<br />";
                                            echo"<ul>";
                                            echo"<li>$links_title</li>";
                                            echo"<br />";
                                            echo$content;
                                            echo"</ul>";
                                            echo"<br /><br />";
                                            */

                                            if($content != NULL) {
                                                if($links_title != NULL) {
                                                    if($newspaper_id != NULL) {

                                                        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO crawler_results
    (title,content,newspaper_id,crawler_id,img_src,category,config_id,status) 
                                                        VALUES ('$links_title','$content','$newspaper_id','$crawler_id','$img_src','$category','$config_id','3')");

                                                        $status = '2';

                                                    } else {
                                                    $status = '-1';
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                $status = '-1';
                                                }
                                            }

                                    }
                }
        }

        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE crawler_queue SET status = '$status' WHERE crawler_id = '$start_crawler_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
}
    echo"Completed";
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE statuz SET status = '2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    } else {
       echo"Not ready yet";
    }


    ?>
```

I appreciate all kinds of help!

Comment: In general i would try to narrow the source of failure down by removing and re-adding blocks.

Comment: Also avoid suppressing error messages with @. It makes finding errors obviously a lot harder.

Comment: I tried that :( The script works when crawling smaller sites, but gives me the error when there is a lot of content. that must mean it has something to do with the execution time

Comment: Could also be a memory issue since. Try increase the memory limit. Do you run your script in browser or from console? Do you run the script once per site or do you try to process multiple sites in one run?

Comment: I've increased the memory to 256M, but it still gives me the error :( I used to run multiple sites at once, but when the error occurred I narrowed down to only 1 site at a time.

Comment: Your log file gives no further information? Can you monitor the memory consumption of your script? The far i understand your script you potentially load a lot of pages in your memory.

Comment: I don't really know much about the error_log. I have added: error_log("Error message\n", 3, "../logs/php.log"); at the top of my script, but I don't know how to make it specify what is going wrong in my script.

Comment: It is weird because my script works when running on localhost